# Excel is closed, but using a lot of resources

Tags: microsoft-excel

## **Versions:**

- Office Home and Business 2016 (last updated [1/?/17](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Office-365-95c8d81d-08ba-42c1-914f-bca4603e1426?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US))
- Windows 10 (last updated [4/5/17](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016251))

## **Issue:**

For the past few days... possibly since the last Windows 10 update (two days ago)... my fan starts going crazy out of nowhere with few programs open. Task Manager indicates Excel is running and using a lot of CPU (See the screenshot below).

*But Excel is not open.*

"End Task" only works for ~5 mins before it starts again.

## **Possibly Relevant:**

I have a few excel files saved on OneDrive.

## **How can I fix this?**

- I am aware that I could [roll back the update](https://www.howtogeek.com/206271/how-to-roll-back-or-uninstall-a-problematic-windows-update/), but I'd rather not
  deal with Windows asking me all the time to restart my computer.
- I could also try deleting my files off oneDrive, but I don't want to
  do that unless I know for sure it's causing the issue.

## Resolution Efforts:

- Google
- End Task

**Screenshot:**

[image: Task Manager screenshot of excel using 24.8% cpu and 43.2 MB of Memory]

Comment: To troubleshoot, you should roll back the suspect update to test if it's actually causing your problem or not.  Also, if you suspect those files are somehow causing it, then test by renaming them to have a non-Excel file extension (like change them to .TMP for testing, and change them back later).

Comment: check if office updates are enabled . diable it after you have rolled back the update @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 suggested

Comment: Are on a network? Shared files? If not, maybe turn off Auto Updates for MS Office.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I rolled back the last update, and that seemed to fix the problem. Could you post that as an answer so I can give you credit please?

Comment: SOLVED - OP waiting for solution post by Techie007.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 above comments.

Comment: Rolling back an update is not a valid solution in my opinion, it's simply a troubleshooting step and/or workaround until an actual fix is found. If you want to answer it yourself explaining exactly what you did (to make it a worthwhile answer) then please do, its acceptable around here. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's apparent that there may have been an issue with the update. The first thing that you should *always* attempt is a restart to your PC. While this "solution" has been said to almost every hardware and software problem, it does sometimes resolve the issue you may be having.

Otherwise, I would try one or more of the following *(the lower you go down the list, the longer the task and more effort you will put into your troubleshooting, but will be more likely to fix your issue).*

- Rolling back your PC to the state *prior* to the update in question

  1. If solved, reinstall the update. If issue persists, continue
- Roll back the update

  1. Uninstall MS Office
  2. Reinstall the update
  3. Reinstall MS Office
- Roll back the update

  1. Uninstall MS Office Suite
  2. [Perform Windows 10 integrity check with CMD Prompt SFC /scannow](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-sfc-command-utility-fix-system-files-windows-10)
  3. Reapply the update
  4. Reinstall MS Office Suite
  5. *If problem **still** persists, scan once more
- Consider technical support
- Fresh Install of Windows 10

  - Warning: This will require reinstalling ALL software. This will *usually* fix all of your problems (as long as they are not hardware related), but will also take the longest. Make sure you have all your software's product/activation keys

> Before attempting any of the above solutions, make sure you **fully understand** what you are doing and understand any possible implications that may come out a result of you performing such task. You are solely responsible for the actions you perform using any of the above methods.